# n-dimensional ln and exp functions

Tags: quaternions, fractals

I have some quaternion functions, like ln and exp. If I want to go to 5-component numbers, I can easily migrate the ln and exp functions by adding in an extra imaginary component. Since 5-component numbers do not have a multiplication operator defined, why not just do exp(ln(Q1) + ln(Q2)) instead of the missing Q1*Q2 functionality?

I tried it out with the quaternion Julia set, and it sort of works. Attached is a figure of the standard Julia set, Z = Z^2 + C.

Why is there no multiplication operator in 5D anyway?

[image]

The exp function is:

```
float mag_vector = std::sqrt(qA->y * qA->y + qA->z * qA->z + qA->w * qA->w);

temp_a_x = qA->x;

qOut->x = std::exp(temp_a_x) * std::cos(mag_vector);

qOut->y = std::exp(temp_a_x) * std::sin(mag_vector) * qA->y / mag_vector;

qOut->z = std::exp(temp_a_x) * std::sin(mag_vector) * qA->z / mag_vector;

qOut->w = std::exp(temp_a_x) * std::sin(mag_vector) * qA->w / mag_vector;
```

To add in a 5th-component, one would have to just alter mag_vector to include it, and then change qA->whatever to qA->a where a is the 5th component.

Comment: How do you define the exponential for 5-component numbers?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra for information on why there is no useful multiplication operator on $\Bbb{R}^5$.

Comment: Thanks Berci. The exp function is defined as exp(q) = exp(float) * cos(|V|), exp(float) * sin(|V|) * V / |V| where float is the x component, and V is the 3-vector y, z, w. This function came from "A Quaternion Algebra Tool Set" by Douglas Sweetser.

Comment: Thanks for the link Rob.

Comment: It's absolutely possible to define a multiplication operation of a 5-dimensional vector space (there are many such operations, in fact). The question want to *do* with this operation, and what *properties* you need it to have. There is no multiplication on a 5-dimensional space which has all of the nice properties of $\mathbb{Q}$ (units, associativity, multiplicative inverses, etc.).

Comment: Thanks the lowdown!

Comment: @shawn_halayka This definition of exponential seems specific to quaternions. How would you generalize it?

Comment: @Berci I edited the question to include the C++ code for exp. To add a dimension, one adds imaginary component to the end of the number. You can also get rid of the w and z components to retrieve the complex exp function. So, it works for complex numbers, quaternions, and 'quintonions'.

Comment: P.S. It obviously also works for the reals, where cos(0) = 1, and so it simplifies to out.x = std::exp(in.x).

Comment: @Kajelad I was wondering if you could name some of the multiplication operators for n > 4?

Comment: @shawn_halayka One trivial example is to define $u\cdot v=0$ for all $u,v$ (this product is commutative and associative, but does not have units or multiplicative inverses). Another is to choose a basis and multiply elementwise, i.e. $(u\cdot v)_i=u_iv_i$ (resulting in a produce which is unital, associative, and commutative, but does not have multiplicative inverses).

Comment: @Kajelad you're the best!

Comment: If you want a multiplication that is both A) associative, and B) extends the complex multiplication (there is an element that behaves like the imaginary unit $i$), then that turns your system into a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$. Implying that, as a real vector space, its dimension must be an even integer. Similarly, if you want to extend the quaternion multiplication and keep associativity, your system must have real dimension that is a multiple of four.

Comment: (cont'd) On the other hand, discarding associativity comes with a high prise. You can no longer discuss third powers of elements. What do you mean by $x^3$? Is it $x(x^2)$? Or $(x^2)x$? Without associativity those might not agree! Actually keeping associativity is difficult beyond quaternions. The octions preserve some nice properties about norms, but lose associativity.

Comment: 5D Conformal Geometric Algebra defines multiplication (with inverse), exp, log over real vector space. The product involved is the geometric product, which generalize conplex and quaternion product. Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometric_algebra

Comment: Thanks everybody!